# How to send XML POST requests using JMeter

Tags: xml, api, testing, jmeter

I have been using the Sampler - HTTP requests to send JSON type API calls but have looked through the JMeter documentation and couldn't find a way to do the same for XML requests. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share what you did to send XML requests?

Comment: Within the HTTP Request sampler, in the body field is where the XML data is entered ie. the body takes JSON or XML data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an "HTTP Request" sampler, you can choose the body you want to send along with the request. You have an input box where you can put either JSON or XML (isn't that the way you use for your JSON?). You can also send a file with the request, so you could select an XML file to send. Both those possibilities should work.

Comment: I would like to test a suite of requests of JSON type followed by the same requests of XML type. Could you suggest a good way of going about this? Would I have to manually change all my JSON requests to XML?